# Canvas.drawBitmap() not placing image correctly

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to overlay a bitmap onto another, placing it at the location the user touches. Here's the code:

```
 public static Bitmap mergeImage(Bitmap base, Bitmap overlay, float x, float y)
 {
    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(base.getWidth(), base.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
     canvas.drawBitmap(base, 0, 0, null);
     canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, x, y, null);
     return mBitmap;
 }
```

The issue here is, even though the x & y coordinates are obtained correctly (I checked), the overlay bitmap does not place correctly.

When around the top left portion of the image, placement is correct. However, as I move right and down, the location seems to scale differently (i.e. if I touch the bottom right corner of the screen, the overlay places somewhere near the middle of the image, if I touch bottom left, it places near the middle left of the image and so on)

Both images have the same density (320).

Edit: New issue, i reduced the sizes of both images and now placement is roughly accurate. But saving the image to SD card skews the overlay image to a different (and quite random) location

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using Matrix for set location and scale x,y

```
    public static Bitmap mergeImage(Bitmap base, Bitmap overlay, float x, float y)
    {
        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(base.getWidth(), base.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
        matrix.postTranslate( x,y);
        canvas.drawBitmap(base, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, null);
        return mBitmap;
    }
```

I spend something similar and I found the solution, you can see my post in the siguiete link

[canvas.drawBitmap bad Location and size (not placing image correctly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202233/canvas-drawbitmap-bad-location-and-size-not-placing-image-correctly)