# canvas.drawBitmap bad Location and size (not placing image correctly)

Tags: java, c#, android, bitmap, android-canvas

Hi everyone and beforehand thanks, I hope are well write because I am doing a simple application that should unite more than two bitmaps in only one, the problem is in which position bitmaps and size Side wrong, and the truth will not find the back for logic given to me that 's fine, in fact it is a Tengo Que code already in c # and PASE java obviously is different sin but have the same principle .

I wonder if you have the way to make the position and size of these images out as this saying in the code,

Sorry for my bad English

CODIGO JAVA

Paint mPaint;

```
    Bitmap image1=BitmapUtils.decodeBase64(Lie.GeFondo().GetImagen());
    Bitmap image2=BitmapUtils.decodeBase64(Utilidades.getImagenTomadabase64());
    Bitmap image3=BitmapUtils.decodeBase64(Lie.GetBanner().GetImagen());
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
    Rect dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
    Rect srcRect1 = new Rect( Foto.GetPosicionDeItems().Getx(),Foto.GetPosicionDeItems().Gety(),Foto.GetTamano().GetWidth(), Foto.GetTamano().GeHeight());
    Rect srcRect3 = new Rect( Lie.GetBanner().GetPosicionDeItems().Getx(), Lie.GetBanner().GetPosicionDeItems().Gety() ,Lie.GetBanner().GetTamano().GetWidth(), Lie.GetBanner().GetTamano().GeHeight());


    Rect srcRect2 = new Rect(0,0,image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight());
    Rect srcRect4 = new Rect(0,0,image3.getWidth(), image3.getHeight());

    dstRect.offset(0, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image1, srcRect, dstRect, null);
    dstRect.offset(image1.getWidth(), 0);
    srcRect1.offset(0, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image2,srcRect2 ,srcRect1 , null);

    srcRect1.offset(image2.getWidth(), 0);
    srcRect3.offset(0, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image3,srcRect4 ,srcRect3 , null);
    srcRect3.offset(image3.getWidth(), 0);
    myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(result);
```

in Java 
see java picture http://i58.tinypic.com/1zywm5u.jpg

C# Code

Ignore the foreach.

System.Drawing.Bitmap Bac = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Lienzo.Fondo.Imagen;
            System.Drawing.Graphics r = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Bac);

```
        if (Lienzo.Fotos != null)
        {
            if (Lienzo.Fotos.Count > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (RADMLIB.Items item in Lienzo.Fotos)
                {

                    System.Drawing.Bitmap img = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Lista[i];
                    r.DrawImage(img, item.PosicionDeItems.X, item.PosicionDeItems.Y, item.Tamano.Width, item.Tamano.Height);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Lienzo.Banner != null)
        {
            r.DrawImage((System.Drawing.Bitmap)Lienzo.Banner.Imagen, Lienzo.Banner.PosicionDeItems.X, Lienzo.Banner.PosicionDeItems.Y, Lienzo.Banner.Tamano.Width, Lienzo.Banner.Tamano.Height);
        }

        return Bac;
```

see c# picture http://i61.tinypic.com/s61wlh.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution 
using Matrix for set location and scale x,y

```
    Bitmap image1=BitmapUtils.decodeBase64(Lie.GeFondo().GetImagen());
    Bitmap image2=BitmapUtils.getResizedBitmap(BitmapUtils.decodeBase64(Utilidades.getImagenTomadabase64()),Foto.GetTamano().GetWidth(),Foto.GetTamano().GeHeight());
    Bitmap image3=BitmapUtils.getResizedBitmap(BitmapUtils.decodeBase64(Lie.GetBanner().GetImagen()),Lie.GetBanner().GetTamano().GetWidth(),Lie.GetBanner().GetTamano().GeHeight());
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);//Create the canvas to your image
    Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
    Rect dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix ();
    matrix.postTranslate( Foto.GetPosicionDeItems().Getx(),Foto.GetPosicionDeItems().Gety());
    matrix2.postTranslate( Lie.GetBanner().GetPosicionDeItems().Getx(),Lie.GetBanner().GetPosicionDeItems().Gety());
    canvas.drawBitmap(image1, srcRect, dstRect, null);
    dstRect.offset(image1.getWidth(), 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image2,matrix , null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image3,matrix2 , null);
```

getResizedBitmap Method

public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

```
    int width = bm.getWidth();

    int height = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;



    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();



    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);



    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;

}
```

see the image

https://lh4.ggpht.com/LXW8kVc3U8qQUHnORI-3H4H-A2hjq92y_oEDsKIs-iBDkVBFTgjGP03xFReCeuyLlg=h900-rw